# Adding defer to optimized javascript in T3 Framework

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, performance, template-framework, t3-framework

I am using [T3 Framework](http://www.t3-framework.org/) as a template for Joomla. In it's options there are options for optimizing Javascript and CSS. If set to ON the framework minifies and joins Javascript to 1 or 2 files that are loaded in the head section of the page.

I would like to add the **defer** attribute to those added scripts. How can that be done?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use the jch_optimize plugin, that provides this kind of functionality: combine, compress, minimize javascript and css, set defer or async for javascript files that exist on a site.

There are both a free and a commercial version and you can compare their features here: https://www.jch-optimize.net/downloads.html

Comment: I know about the specific plugin, but I was asking for a way to change the code and insert it my self.

Comment: @dfk_7677:: I guess this should be done somewhere in the T3, but presently I don't know if this is something that can be achieved without modifying the core T3 code.